# Silverlight 3 Navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight

After installing silverlight 3 from silverlight 3 Beta, the Frame control doesnt seem to work any more... is this corrent.. I get no error and no navigation..

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="Frames" Source="Home"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                <navcore:UriMapper>
                    <navcore:UriMapping Uri="Home" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml" />
                </navcore:UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one mapping, so you'll only get one page. The default mapper when you create a navigation project looks like this:

```
<navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
```

The second mapping will look for a view based on the page name specified.

Comment: Problem is it doesnt navigate.. it just remains like "http://localhost/ProjectName/Default.aspx"

Comment: My error was not in my coding, it was visual studios 2010 beta... the code works fine in visual studio 2008.. 
@Soviut thanks for the advise I will do that from no own